# Chain animations not working with AnimatorSet

Tags: java, android, animatorset

I want to "blink" a view 3x (scale down and back up, repeat 3x). It works, but not with AnimatorSet.

This works:

```
ibOffers.animate().scaleX(0.7f).scaleY(0.7f).setDuration(200).withEndAction(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        ibOffers.animate().scaleX(1.0f).scaleY(1.0f).setDuration(200).withEndAction(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                ibOffers.animate().scaleX(0.7f).scaleY(0.7f).setDuration(200).withEndAction(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        ibOffers.animate().scaleX(1.0f).scaleY(1.0f).setDuration(200).withEndAction(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                ibOffers.animate().scaleX(0.7f).scaleY(0.7f).setDuration(200).withEndAction(new Runnable() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        ibOffers.animate().scaleX(1.0f).scaleY(1.0f).setDuration(200).withEndAction(new Runnable() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void run() {

                                            }
                                        });
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
});
```

But this doesn't:

```
final ObjectAnimator scaleDownAnimation =
        ObjectAnimator.ofPropertyValuesHolder(ibOffers,
                PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat(View.SCALE_X,0.7f),
                PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat(View.SCALE_Y,0.7f))
        .setDuration(200);

final ObjectAnimator scaleBackAnimation =
        ObjectAnimator.ofPropertyValuesHolder(ibOffers,
                PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat(View.SCALE_X,1f),
                PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat(View.SCALE_Y,1f))
                .setDuration(200);

AnimatorSet s = new AnimatorSet();
s.playSequentially(scaleDownAnimation,
        scaleBackAnimation,
        scaleDownAnimation,
        scaleBackAnimation,
        scaleDownAnimation,
        scaleBackAnimation);
```

What am I missing? I just want to improve the first code block as it looks ugly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not starting it:

```
s.start();
```

Also, you cannot reuse the `ObjectAnimator`. So, you have to create three copies of each step of the animation. You can use a small utility method to not duplicate as much code.

Your complete sequence will be:

```
ObjectAnimator getScaleAnimation(View v, float scale, int duration) {
    return ObjectAnimator.ofPropertyValuesHolder(v,
        PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat(View.SCALE_X, scale),
        PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat(View.SCALE_Y, scale))
        .setDuration(duration);
}

AnimatorSet s = new AnimatorSet();
s.playSequentially(
    getScaleAnimation(ibOffers, 0.7f, 250),
    getScaleAnimation(ibOffers, 1.2f, 250),
    getScaleAnimation(ibOffers, 0.7f, 250),
    getScaleAnimation(ibOffers, 1.2f, 250),
    getScaleAnimation(ibOffers, 0.7f, 250),
    getScaleAnimation(ibOffers, 1.0f, 250));

s.start();
```

Comment: Could you try to do just one "blink"?

Comment: See my updated answer. The issue was that you cannot reuse the `ObjectAnimator`, so you have to create 3 copies of each (that was my suspicion and the reason of my previous comment).